# Jmeter, BeanShell Sampler and Summary Report

Tags: java, jmeter

- Thread Group

  - BeanShell Sampler (calcuate parameter and put in user defined variable)
  - Loop

    - Java Sampler (with parameters).

Inside the Summary Report I see that the BeanShell Sampler are listed, and I don't want this as it affects the final average throughput ; how can this be remedied? Is there a substitute object?
I noticed that if I put in a BeanSell Pre Processor it gets called every time a Java sampler is run, which I don't want (tell me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke the following function anywhere in your Beanshell Sampler:

```
SampleResult.setIgnore();
```

More information: [SampleResult.setIgnore() JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--)

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) as Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell, see [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for details.